# How to declare PHP (web) and ruby (worker) in Procfile

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to create a facebook web app (i need the web to be PHP) with a worker to process tasks vie the messaging queue add on ( i need it in Rube - i think..).

When i added a Gemfile, heroku stopped identifying my app as PHP at all.

So i am hoping that adding 'web: "PHP declaration"' to the procfile will solve my problem, but cant seem to find documentation on how to do that.

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/6/20/the_new_heroku_1_process_model_procfile/

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

is there a different way to achieve my goal?
Any suggestions are more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the ruby code separate to the php? Are they in the same file?

Comment: Yes, the ruby code is in a separate file, but in the same app.
I (think I) need it to communicate with the RabbitMQ and then activate other PHP-facebook related logic which i want to run in the background...

Comment: Okay, are you currently running them on the Facebook server or your own server? Could you upload a snippet?